# Tor how to create onion mirror links for existing site

Tags: tor

I have seen in most of the market places in darknet has few different mirror links. Wondering how could I configure to have an existing website to have multiple mirror links?

Following is the approach I have taken. However, I'd think there could be a better way of doing this.

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/a_service
HiddenServicePort 80

HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/b_service
HiddenServicePort 80

HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/c_service
HiddenServicePort 80
```

Comment: Don't run all the hidden services on the same machine or Tor instance.  That isn't really mirroring because if the underlying service, or the entire machine goes down, all onion addresses stop working.  Realistically, each of those hidden services should be on different servers in different locations, and each reverse proxy to another server that is completely inaccessible to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a mirror for same location it is a way but it is not secure even you need to use reverse proxy and the mirror should be on different servers with a load balancing.

Reference:https://tor.wittyanswer.com/tor-hidden-services-load-balancing-onionbalance-onion-mirror-links/